# Sum some of Dataframe with special characters

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame as below:

| A-open | A-close | A-total | G-open | G-close | G-total | F-open | F-close | F-total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 8 | 2 | 0 |

I want to sum all open and close for each title, my desirable table is:

| A-open | A-close | A-total | G-open | G-close | G-total | F-open | F-close | F-total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 10 |

Comment: Do you only have 3 different letter columns or are there more?

Comment: No, I have more...  @EmiOB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of the different sets of letter columns, by splitting all the column names by '-' and keeping the first letter/letters, putting the output into a set to remove duplicates:

```
letters = list({i.split('-')[0] for i in df.columns.to_list()})
print(letters)
{'A', 'F', 'G'}
```

Then you can loop through these, and calculate the total column for each, by adding the open and close:

```
for l in letters:
    df[l + '-total'] = df[l + '-open'] + df[l + '-close']
```

Final df:

```
   A-open  A-close  A-total  G-open  G-close  G-total  F-open  F-close  F-total
0       1        4        5       3        5        8       8        2       10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the id before the dash and use it to `groupby`+`sum` on the columns:

```
groups = df.columns.str.split('-').str[0]
d = df.groupby(groups, axis=1).sum().add_suffix('-total')
```

output:

```
   A-total  F-total  G-total
0        5       10        8
```

to insert/replace as columns:

```
df[d.columns] = d
```

output:

```
   A-open  A-close  A-total  G-open  G-close  G-total  F-open  F-close  F-total
0       1        4        5       3        5        8       8        2       10
```

*NB. this is assuming the 'X-total' columns are initially absent or empty. If not empty:*

```
df[d.columns] = d-df[d.columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can convert to a MultiIndex using [`str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html#pandas-series-str-rsplit) on the columns the [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html) so that the top level columns are "open", "close", and "total". The benefit of a MultiIndex is that we can use index alignment to do the computations and the computations can be done idiomatically:

```
# Create MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('-', n=1, expand=True).swaplevel()

# Multi Index allows for idiomatic computations like this:
df['total'] = df['open'] + df['close']

# Collapse MultiIndex
df.columns = [f'{b}-{a}' for (a, b) in df.columns]
```

`df`:

```
   A-open  A-close  A-total  G-open  G-close  G-total  F-open  F-close  F-total
0       1        4        5       3        5        8       8        2       10
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A-open': [1], 'A-close': [4], 'A-total': [0], 'G-open': [3],
    'G-close': [5], 'G-total': [0], 'F-open': [8], 'F-close': [2],
    'F-total': [0]
})
```